# least squared optimization

Tags: optimization, cvxpy

I want to decompose a list of 3D vectors  $X_j$ as linear combination of five 3D verctors $C_k$

$$X_j= \sum_{i=1}^{5}{w_{ji}C_i}$$ both $X_j$ and $C_i$ are 3 components vectors

$$C= \begin{bmatrix} C_{11} & C_{12}  & C_{13}  \\ C_{21} & C_{22}  & C_{23} \\ ... \\  \\ C_{51} & C_{52}  & C_{53} \end{bmatrix}$$

$$W= \begin{bmatrix} W_{11} & W_{12} &...   & W_{15}  \\ W_{21} & W_{22} &...   & W_{25}  \\ ... \\  \\ W_{m1} & W_{m2} &...   & W_{m5}  \end{bmatrix}$$

$$X= \begin{bmatrix} X_{11} & X_{12}  & X_{13}  \\ X_{21} & X_{22}  & X_{23} \\ ... \\  \\ X_{m1} & X_{m2}  & X_{n3} \end{bmatrix}$$
i think this is a least squared optimization problem, but i am unable to correctly formulate it in the standard form $\left \|b-Ax \right \|^2$ and implement it in cvxpy.

$$\left \| X_j- \sum_{i=1}^{5}{w_{ji}C_i}  \right \|^2$$

Comment: $W$ is the unknown here, correct? We assume $X$ and $C$ are fixed, right?

Comment: Yes $W$ is unknown and $X$ and $C$ are are fixed.

Comment: Why implement in CVXPY if there's a closed form solution?

Comment: what is the colosed form solution for this problem ?